# how to append id's separated by comma?

Tags: php

I am building an E-commerce website and for my `cart.php` page I want to collect all the ids of the items which is added to cart and then send these ids through URL to my `success.php` so that here I can retrieve these ids and update my database status to confirmed for particular user. I tried using array for collecting ids but then i dont know how to write sql query to update table using array, i also tried `implode()` function but then i am getting error in query. I need code for collecting ids, sending these ids through URL, retrieving the ids, and query to update. 
My Code:

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $ids = array();
    while ($num_rows > 0) { 
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       $ids[] = $row['item_id'];
       $num_rows--;
    }
    $id = implode(', ', $ids);?>
    <td><a href="success.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn- 
    primary">Confirm Order</a></td>
```

Comment: You are right to be looking at implode() but you also need explode() at the other end to turn it back into an array you can work with.

Comment: Could you share the rest of the code which you have written to push the records to the database?

Comment: @ValerianPereira Here: <?php  $item_id=$_GET['id'];
$user_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$query="UPDATE users_items SET status='Confirmed' where item_id='$item_id' and user_id='$user_id'";
$result= mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>

Comment: @MatthewPage But then how would i send these ids through URL and write one query to update to all rows with these ids. Can you write the code for me?

Comment: In success.php you can use explode to get the array back from the GET['id'] variable. Then you'll need to use a foreach loop to build an sql query SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id='1' OR id='2' OR id='3' - I'm not going to write the code for you.

Comment: @MatthewPage Thanks I understood your point.

Answer (score 0):

Code to send the IDs

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $ids=array();
    while ($num_rows > 0) { 
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
       $ids[]=$row['item_id'];
       $num_rows--;
    }
    $id= implode(',', $ids);?>
    <td><a href="success.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn- 
    primary">Confirm Order</a></td>
```

Code to update the DB using the IDs, based on the snippet you shared in the comments

```
<?php 
   $item_id=$_GET['id']; 
   $user_id=$_SESSION['id']; 
   $query="UPDATE users_items SET status='Confirmed' WHERE item_id='$item_id' AND user_id IN (".$item_id.")"; 
   // Debug-Query Formation: //echo $query;
   $result= mysqli_query($con, $query); 
?>
```

Hope this helps